# Use filename as variable when replacing text in files

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext3

Is it possible to reference to current file's name when using find/replace in files in sublime text? Or possibly in other text editor?

Comment: Short answer: no. Hacky answer: probably if you create your [own plugin](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/plugin-basics)

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy using [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), just select "Language C# Statement(s)", and do something like this:

```
var files = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\SomePath").GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach(var fileInfo in files)
{
    var text = File.ReadAllText(fileInfo.FullName);
    text = Regex.Replace(text, "pattern", fileInfo.Name); // Replace "pattern" with filename
    File.WriteAllText(fileInfo.FullName, text);
}
```

Comment: You saved my day! 550 html files renamed in 3 sec...