# Replace specific text in file with it's own Filename using linqpad, C#, and regex

Tags: c#, regex, linqpad

Operating on windows 10 32bit at the moment unfortunately. I'm editing cuesheets to match back up with mp3s and m4bs whose file names have changed. I'm looking for a method to easily automate the process. Because I generally name cuesheets to match the name of the paired audio file, I thought the simplest method would just be to grab it's own file name (hopefully without it's file extension). I have the regex to select the text I want to replace working just fine in notepad++ and several other apps as well. Sadly, I have yet to find a prebuilt find and replace solution that has the file's own name that is being edited as a variable. So, I spent some time searching and the most promising thing I found was in another post ([Use filename as variable when replacing text in files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890678/use-filename-as-variable-when-replacing-text-in-files)).

Example line in cue file:

> FILE "Alfred Minoa.1998 - Animals of The Sahara - Documentary.m4b" MP4

Portion to be replaced:

> Alfred Minoa.1988 - Animals of The Sahara - Documentary

New names of m4b & cue file:

> Alfred Minoa - Animals of The Sahara - Documentary.cue

> Alfred Minoa - Animals of The Sahara - Documentary.m4b

Goal is to replace text "Alfred Minoa.1998 - Animals of The Sahara - Documentary" inside the cue file with name of the cue file minus the ".cue" file Extension.

**Updated and now working code thanks to input from Fildor**

Update: Figured out the last tidbit **Solved**

Here's the code for anyone that might be looking to acheive the same thing or something similar.

```
    var files = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\TestFolder\).GetFiles("*.cue", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach(var fileInfo in files)
    {
        var text = File.ReadAllText(fileInfo.FullName);
        string TrimmedText = fileInfo.Name; // Get Filename into String
        TrimmedText = TrimmedText.Substring(0, TrimmedText.Length - 4); // Trim File Extension from filename
        text = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=FILE "").+?(?=\...."")", TrimmedText); // Replace "pattern" with filename
        File.WriteAllText(fileInfo.FullName, text);
    }
```

Thank you to those who took the time to contribute.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! can you share with us the text you want to replace (relevant snippet only)?

Comment: Sure, Edited post to include. Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: You need to escape " ... as is, your regex is `@"(?<=FILE "` and the rest is invalid syntax.

Comment: BTW: It's always a good idea to post the error you are getting. If it's an exception then message and stacktrace, if it's a UI Error Messagebox, then the message (as _text_ not image).

Comment: _"and the rest is invalid syntax."_ correction: `Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=FILE ")` it is and the following . would be interpreted as member access, but string has no member "+?" ... :)

Comment: (?<=FILE ").+?(?=\....")  works fine as shown here http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dFILE+%22%29.%2b%3f%28%3f%3d%5c....%22%29&i=FILE+%22Alfred+Minoa.1998+-+Animals+of+The+Sahara+-+Documentary.m4b%22+MP4 with the above example, I understand there are apparently syntax errors as I know next to nothing about c#. What I don't know is why, and how to fix it when the regex works with the .net library as far as I can tell. Thank you for looking I appreciate the feedback,

Comment: Ah, sorry. Try: `@"(?<=FILE "").+?(?=\...."")"` => [Verbatim text - @ in variables, attributes, and string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) : _"Only a quote escape sequence ("") isn't interpreted literally; it produces one double quotation mark."_

Comment: Wow, Thank you... first step accomplished... now I just need to learn how to trim off the last four characters in c# before it writes to file, and it will work for 99% of my cue files. a big improvement over copy and paste even as is I could just Find and replace ".cue" with nothing. That would be sloppy, and step more than necessary though. with your kindly provided edit... it's working code now at least.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what your search string is trying to do, but you could try this.

```
string searchStr   = @"FILE \"".+?\""" ;
string replacement = @$"FILE ""{System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileInfo.Name)}""" ;
text = Regex.Replace(text, searchStr, replacement);
```

Regex syntax sometimes varies between languages but seeing you are using LinqPad, you can use the Ctrl-Shift-F1 to test the search part of the regex in C# (but not the replace)

Answer (score 0):

You could find enclosing `FILE` and `MP4` using the following regex:

```
(?:(FILE "").*("" (MP4|M4B)))
```

Fiddle: https://regex101.com/r/RU70xd/2

Then you can use it this way:

```
string t = "FILE \"Alfred Minoa.1998 - Animals of The Sahara - Documentary.m4b\" MP4";
string pat = "(?:(FILE \").*(\" (MP4|M4B)))";
Regex rx = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.Compiled
   | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
string nt = rx.Replace(t, "$1TEST$2");
Console.WriteLine(nt);
```

It will prints

```
FILE "TEST" MP4
```

You can replace the `TEST` with whatever string you wanted, but keep both enclosure (the `$1` and `$2`).

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vjY7qZ

Comment: I thought about that, but "MP4" is not a constant between files.  as some are for mp3s or flac, Then I thought something like "(?:(FILE \").*(\.m\w\w\"))"? Looking at your example as that would work for the majority being mp3 or m4b. I also don't want to replace the file extension in the file as I am trying to grab the filename of the cue file that just happens to match that of the audio file. it's years since I coded much of anything and that was primarily VB or C++ so I am very rusty and not up on C# a t all. just trying to find a solution to a problem. not set on linqpad or c# either

Comment: @EricC you can use or operator (`|`), using regex without some anchor/reference points may risk hitting something else though so I often overspecified somestuff. use whatever you think right, i'm here to chip in ideas. though, if we can go beyond text manipulation, you should consider proper `cue` authoring tools or at least a library that deals with it.

Comment: Right general idea, although I'd need to figure how to fit that in with grabbing the name of the cue file.... which I'm assuming will grab the file extension with it... which I would then have to trim off before having it basically pasted into the file... looks like if I want to do this I might have to learn c# there's a program called cuetools that will do it. but in a fundamentally different way and won't work for cuesheets for m4bs. Manual copy and paste is too tedious for so many files. and for whatever reason I can't make autohotkey to work worth anything on this old tablet pc.

Comment: I'll think on it more, thank you for taking the time and your input. I'm probably too tired to have anything but diminishing returns right now. Using look ahead and look behind in regex was the only consistent method I could think of to select the desired text. Like here http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dFILE+%22%29.%2b%3f%28%3f%3d%5c....%22%29&i=FILE+%22Alfred+Minoa.1998+-+Animals+of+The+Sahara+-+Documentary.m4b%22+MP4 works like a charm in notepad++ problem being there's no variable to just plug the filename into the find & Replace function. Seems like a simple goal. oh well